# is it possible to create an android 1.5.1 app using Android Studio?

Tags: android

is it possible to create an Android 1.5.1 app using Android Studio?

Yes it is old but still used...

It only has to read 3 different txt files which are located on local network, containing 1 line of text each and display it under each other in portrait view. 
Refresh ones a minute should be ok.
And it has to have a dropdown menu so you can choose which number of device it is, so from 1-10 is ok and according that read the txt files which belongs to that device nr.

I can't use a webpage because i cannot create a local server for it. So i need a little app.

To create the txt files i use a windows program.
I use Livecode (since short) but it can't create apps below Android froyo 2.2.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. As i don't know anything about java.
It's only for local use, nothing commercial or anything

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Try to create for 2.2 and set the API level in the manifest by hands. You will likely get some errors, you will have to fix them.

Comment: Ok then maybe i could also use Livecode (easier for me), then op the APK with an APK tool, adjust the manifest and build the APK again with the same tool. I will have a try if it will work.

Comment: I tried to follow RunRev's instructions to re-build a LiveCode app for Android after decompiling it. I re-built it correctly with APK-tool and it was signed and verified, but it wouldn't run on my Android 2.3.3. I'm pretty sure you won't be able to get it running on your Anroid 1.5.1.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply and for testing it. Were did you find the instructions exactly from Runrev? on their Livecode Forum?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using PhoneGap (Cordova) http://phonegap.com which is basically a HTML-Webview, wrapped up in an App, so you can code the whole thing using JavaScript, and it is still a real app.

With this it should be very easy to do that, even if you "don't speak Java".

But to answer your initial question, yes it should be possible to create an Android App for 1.5.1 with Android Studio. You just need to install the right SDK/Packages etc with the SDK Manager.

Have fun coding.

Comment: I have just tried that -- the pop-up allows to choose API=3, but all templates require at least API 7. :)

Comment: Great! Thank you, i will have a look. I also tried a quick(just a knob) thing on MIT, it installs but won't run. Yes i have the DSK for it installed.